# we've gone over all the instruments and controls

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Driving school

**Driving Instructor**: OK, Mario, **we've gone over all** the instruments and controls.

**Man**: Uhum.

**Driving Instructor**: Are you familiar with those?

**Man**: Yeah.

**Driving Instructor**: OK. Before we set the car in motion,   we just want to double check that your seat is comfortable.

**Man**: Yes, good.

**Driving Instructor**: OK. Your seat belt is on properly.

**Man**: Uhmm.

**Driving Instructor**: OK.  Now the last thing you want to do is to check that mirror.

**Man**: Yeah.

**Driving Instructor**: Make sure your mirrors are set up OK. Good. Then we're going to start the car. OK. Your right foot on the brake. Now, put it into the drive position.

---

What does "**we've gone over all** the instruments and controls" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go over

```
1.
consider, examine, or check something.
"I want to go over these plans with you again
```

From

[Oxford Languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/)

The man has properly studied the instruments and controls: where the speedometer is, how to turn on the lights, ...

.